# Callback on client side does not get get triggered from signalR back end

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr.client

I'm having trouble with the server side not communicating with the client side. I receive data on the back end once it's sent from the client, however, it will not work vice versa (when the data is sent back to the client).

**My project setup:**

- Created an empty ASP.NET application with framework 4.6.2
- Installed nuget package 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR' v2.4.0
- Using jQuery 3.3.1
- Added a startup class and inserted 'app.MapSignalR();' into the
  configuration method
- Added a hub with one method for communicating back and forth with the
  client
- Added a js file for starting up the hub and communicating with the
  server

**I have tried the following with no success:**

- Using framework 4.5
- Using an older version of jQuery
- Logging data on
  back end (*which I do receive data from the client*)
- Tried sending back the message to ALL clients (Clients.All) opposed to just the caller
- Re-creating a new
  project for signalR
- Made sure that there were NO JS errors
- Ran locally in MULTIPLE browsers (Chrome & Edge)

**index.aspx:**

```
<script src="/js/third_party/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/third_party/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="/js/third_party/jquery.signalR-2.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src='/signalr/js'></script>
<script src="/js/client.js"></script>
```

**client.js:**

```
var conn = null;

$(function () {

    $.connection.hub.stateChanged(connectionStateChanged);
    $.connection.hub.start({ waitForPageLoad: false });
    conn = $.connection.login;

    function connectionStateChanged(state) {

        switch (state.newState) {
            case 1: // Connected
                conn.server.announce('This is an announcement.'); // Works fine and sends the message
                break;
        }

    }

    // I'm using '.client', so there is no reason why this should not be triggered
    conn.client.onAnnounce = function (message) {
        alert(message); // Does NOT receive the message back
        debugger;
    }
```

**Login.cs:**

```
public class Login : Hub
{
    public void Announce(string message)
    {
        // I receive the data here from the client... but it does not get sent back to the client
        Clients.Caller.onAnnounce(message);
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(AutoPlayer.Startup))]
namespace SignalRTest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the server to receive a message, the server to send that same message back to the client, and for the client to alert the message.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying different things, it was due to this line of code:

```
$.connection.hub.start({ **waitForPageLoad: false** });
```

Removing the 'waitForPageLoad' setting, or by setting it to true fixed it.

"*waitForPageLoad - Determines if SignalR should wait until the page is entirely loaded to start the connection (defaults to true).*"

I assume this was due to the client JS file not being loaded fully, by the time the server was calling back to the client (where 'conn.client.onAnnounce' did not exist yet). Figured I'd see a JS error in the console if this really is the case... but I guess not.